# Select between MongoRepository and JPARepository at startup

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, dao

I am trying to build a library that supports both Mongo and JPA Data access in a Spring Application.
I created both DAO classes (one extends `MongoRepository`, the other `JPARepository`). The library should be able to run whether there's a database connection or not. When i run my application, both DAO classes are compiled and I get an error because Spring tries to connect to the databases.
Is there a way to generate the DAO dynamically? or to deactivate one of the DAO classes altogether?

I tried to use `@ConditionalOnProperties` to deactivate the DAO but it didn't work (could be an error on my part). 
I thought about implementing a factory to generate my DAO at runtime but i wouldn't know how to go about it and extend the appropriate interface.

Comment: I don't know your configuration but the fastest solution I may think is to use 2 different spring profile; one for JPA and one for Mongo

Comment: I don't think *@ConditionalOnProperties* will help you out. because, if you have two different data base like (mongodb,mysql) using this property you can choose which one want to use.